# How can i make the recursion in my Minesweeper GUI be quicker?

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, optimization, game-development

I am working on a minesweeper game in Java Swing, it works correctly, however, when I am checking for 0s that are adjacent to other 0s, the program becomes incredibly slow (20 to 23 seconds) I am trying to recursively access each JButton via a depth first search. Is there any way I could do this quicker?

[Minesweeper GUI Link](https://stackoverflow.com)
This link shows the problem. Whenever I click a 0 on the grid, it takes too long for my program to click each adjacent button. I tried using a stack and a queue and they are both just about as slow. My Main class deals with the bomb logic and my GUIArray class deals with creating the GUI and in the findZero method of the GUIArray class is where the recursion takes place (the doClick() method is the recursive call). Is there anyway I could optimize this to make clicking a button with a 0 almost instant? Thank you for any help!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GUIArray {
    private static final int ROWS = 14;
    private static final int COLS = 18;
    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 800;
    private static int bombCount = 0;
    private static final JLabel countLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(bombCount));
    public int i = 0;
    public int n = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Font f1 = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 14);
        //color for when the button has been clicked
        Color color2 = new Color(153, 102, 0);
        Color color3 = new Color(102, 51, 0);

        JButton[][] button = new JButton[ROWS][COLS];
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        //panel.add(countLabel);

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < COLS; n++) {
                final int row = i;
                final int col = n;
                button[i][n] = new JButton(Main.finalArr[i][n]);
                panel.add(button[i][n]);
                Color buttonColor;
                if ((i + n) % 2 == 0){
                    buttonColor = Color.GREEN.darker();
                    button[i][n].setBackground(buttonColor);
                }
                else{
                    buttonColor = Color.GREEN.darker().darker();
                    button[i][n].setBackground(buttonColor);
                }
                button[i][n].setForeground(button[i][n].getBackground());
                button[i][n].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){
                            button[row][col].setBackground(Color.RED.brighter());
                            button[row][col].setForeground(Color.RED.brighter());
                        }
                        //bombCount++;
                        //updateCountLabel();
                    }
                });
                ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        switch (button[row][col].getLabel()){
                            case ("x"):
                                System.exit(0);
                            case ("0"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                                int[] indices = findIndex(button, button[row][col]);
                                findZero(button, indices[0], indices[1]);
                                break;
                            case ("1"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.RED.brighter());
                                break;
                            case ("2"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                                break;
                            case ("3"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                                break;
                            case ("4"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
                                break;
                            case ("5"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
                                break;
                            case ("6"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.PINK);
                                break;
                            case ("7"):
                                button[row][col].setForeground(Color.YELLOW.darker().darker());
                                break;
                        }

                        if (button[row][col].getBackground().equals(Color.GREEN.darker())){
                            button[row][col].setBackground(color2);
                        }                           //this is to change the background color once it has been clicked
                        else {
                            button[row][col].setBackground(color3);
                        }


                        if (button[row][col].getLabel().equals("x")){
                            System.exit(0);
                        }


                    }
                };
                button[i][n].addActionListener(listener);
            }
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void updateCountLabel() {
        countLabel.setText("Bombs: " + bombCount);
    }


    public static int[] findIndex(JButton[][] buttons, JButton targetButton) {
        //initialize with indices that aren't in the array
        int[] indices = {-1, -1};


        //loop through the array trying to find the button that matches the target
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                if (buttons[i][j] == targetButton) {
                    indices[0] = i;
                    indices[1] = j;
                    return indices; // Return the indices and exit the loop
                }
            }
        }

        return indices; // If the button is not found, return the default invalid indices
    }

    public static void findZero(JButton[][] buttons, int row, int col){

        buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);
        //check up left
        if (isValid(row - 1, col - 1)){
            if (buttons[row - 1][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row - 1][col - 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row - 1][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row - 1][col - 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
        //check up
        if (isValid(row - 1, col)){
            if (buttons[row - 1][col].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row - 1][col].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row - 1][col].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row - 1][col].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
        //check up right
        if (isValid(row - 1, col + 1)){
            if (buttons[row - 1][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row - 1][col + 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row - 1][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row - 1][col + 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
        //check left
        if (isValid(row, col - 1)){
            if (buttons[row][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row][col - 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row][col - 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }
        //check right
        if (isValid(row, col + 1)){
            if (buttons[row][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row][col + 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row][col + 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }
        //check down left
        if (isValid(row + 1, col - 1)){
            if (buttons[row + 1][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row + 1][col - 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row + 1][col - 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row + 1][col - 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }
        //check down
        if (isValid(row + 1, col)){
            if (buttons[row + 1][col].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row + 1][col].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row + 1][col].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row + 1][col].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }
        //check down right
        if (isValid(row + 1, col + 1)){
            if (buttons[row + 1][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                buttons[row + 1][col + 1].doClick();
            }
            else {
                if (!buttons[row + 1][col + 1].getText().equals("0")){
                    buttons[row + 1][col + 1].doClick();
                    buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean isValid(int row, int column) {
        return row >= 0 && row < 14 && column >= 0 && column < 18;
    }

}
```

Comment: Without looking at your code: you should not inspect buttons, but keep a separate array with the information. Never use the GUI elements as your basis for keeping state.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this Wikipedia [article describing the  MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: Why do you search for the button clicked, instead of giving each its own listener so you just know which one was clicked? Also, in `findZero` there is no check for whether a button is still enabled. Would the same button be able to be "clicked" with `doClick()` multiple times in the same run? On first reading, I don't see why not. Finally, any long-running process should not be done on the event dispatch thread. And what trincot said.

Comment: Thank you so much I made it a little quicker!